# Power BI doesn't reflect changed done in Edit Queries mode even after applying changes

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using Power BI (May 2020 edition) and I've encountered a very weird problem. My visuals are based on SQL Server Stored Procedure. When I initially displayed data on visuals, I realized I need to add extra column on backend and switch columns on visual. So, I did the following:

1. I modified my Stored Procedure and applied changes on back-end
2. I navigated to Data View and clicked on Edit Queries menu item. Then I right-clicked on the column I needed to move and clicked "Move Right". This way 2 columns swapped the order in which they were displayed.
   Then I clicked Refresh All and after a while got all my changes - recently added column from SP and swapped columns displayed correctly on Edit Queries window.

After all these manipulations I clicked Close & Apply and was redirected to Data View of my Visuals. None of the changes were reflected. I went to Report View - the same thing, of course.

Did I do anything wrong or it's a known bug that hopefully has workaround?

Appreciate everybody's help.

P.S. I was able to refresh the data by right-clicking on "Query" dropdown on Data View and clicking "Refresh Data". However, columns order still not resolved. Looks like everything we do under Edit Queries is not reflected in May 2020 edition. Please correct me if I'm wrong or if there is a workaround. Unfortunately I can't upgrade to newer version as our server doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue - instead of going to Edit Query mode, I simply dragged fields to appropriate place in Report Mode, Visualizations pane. But I still remain puzzled why Edit Queries changes are not reflected when Close & Apply is clicked.